# OS X: Can I paste plain text by default?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-leopard, clipboard

This is a version of [Windows XP: Can I paste plain text by default](https://superuser.com/questions/11641/windows-xp-can-i-paste-plain-text-by-default) for **Mac** users. This drives me insane as well.

Whenever I cut and paste ***anything*** from one app to another in OS X it carries formatting with it. The only exception is when using a text editor like TextMate. I don't want text I copied from a website or Pages to paste with formatting in iChat, etc.

Does anyone know a way I can turn this off by default, or is there an app that will do it for me?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go:
https://www.engadget.com/2009-07-07-tuaw-tip-paste-without-formatting-by-default.html
[image]

> There's an answer, thanks to the Keyboard & Mouse pane in System Preferences. If you click the Keyboard Shortcuts tab, you can assign "Paste Without Formatting" and/or "Paste and Match Style" to Command + V for all applications. Just click the `+` button under the list, type in the name of the appropriate menu items, and press ⌘-V in the Keyboard Shortcut box.
>
> One note: [Panic](https://panic.com/) designer Neven Mrgan found that using this tip means you [won't be able to paste images](https://twitter.com/mrgan/status/2521320331) into iChat using Command + V. Dragging and dropping (or choosing Paste from the Edit menu) still works, though. Update: If you [explicitly add ⌘-V in as a shortcut for Paste](https://twitter.com/mrgan/status/2521860808) that's specific to iChat, you can restore the image paste capability without breaking the global shortcut.

Comment: Be careful doing this. It breaks pasting into some text fields, like the subject of a Mail.app message.

Learn to use the "Paste and Match Formatting" shortcut when you need to, instead.

Comment: Why the down vote, there is a note near the end of the post saying "Update: If you explicitly add ⌘-V in as a shortcut for Paste that's specific to iChat, you can restore the image paste capability without breaking the global shortcut."  I assume you can do the same for Mail.app

Answer (score 1):

[PTH Pasteboard](http://pth.com/products/pthpasteboard/) gives you this functionality plus a whole lot more.  Multiple clipboards, running scripts (python, ruby, bash, etc...) before being pasted, and persistent clipboard history across reboots are some of my favorite features.

I think I bought this utility faster than any other shareware ever, it's a steal at $25.

Comment: How exactly can you change this default in PTH Pasteboard? Thanks.

Comment: OK, I've found it, but that's not really CMD+V paste :-(

Comment: Goto PTH Pasteboard Preferences, Pasteboards tab, select Main from the source list on the left, and then check the  "As Plaintext" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is, [CleanBoard](https://cleanboard.app) which is a lightweight MacOS app that removes any formatting or special characters from your copied text by hitting the copy-shortcut twice. Great if you don't want to remember those complicated keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).