# Ubuntu Linux: Can I paste plain text by default?

Tags: ubuntu, copy-paste, text-formatting, character-encoding, characters

(Similar to [my earlier question about Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/11641/windows-xp-can-i-paste-plain-text-by-default/11653#11653) and [darren_n's follow-up for Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/11731/os-x-can-i-paste-plain-text-by-default).)

I regularly copy and paste text between spreadsheets, emails, browser windows, etc. I can't think of a single time when I've wanted to keep the formatting from the source text.

I already know about the following workarounds:

- In OpenOffice, click “Edit” → “Paste Special”
  or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>,
  then click “Unformatted Text”
- Paste to Text Editor and copy from there

What I want is to tell Ubuntu to just do this by default.

Is this possible?

Comment: You'd have to modify the way the clipboard works, *or* the copying functionality of every application ever. Have you tried any alternative clipboard managers?

Answer (score 20):

In Ubuntu 11.04 and higher I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> to paste plain text.

Comment: This works in 12.04 as well.

Comment: do you know if/where we can customize this shortcut?

Comment: My Ubuntu is 16.04.2 LTS with KDE and your solution does not work. Maybe there's been some changes over the years, but frankly I think the solution might be specific to your desktop environment and/or clipboard manager. What were they? My bet is there's no universal solution for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the select - middleclick action, which on Unix only copies text (and this is cited as a drawback when promoting real copy-paste of rich objects).

What happens (I'm guessing a bit, but I'm fairly sure I'm right) is that OpenOffice recognizes characters in a similar fashion to Markdown (actually, the other way round: OO came first), and formats them.

For example, in OO, if you start typing `"* text"` and press Enter, you start an unordered bulleted list. Typing `- text` gets you a bulleted list starting with emdash. `1. text` starts an ordered list. All automatically.

So what I mean is that this is not an Ubuntu problem, but the Office Suite trying to DWYM. Which, really, seems the best course here. If I copied your question into OO, I'd prefer the formatting to remain, otherwise I'd copy it into e.g. Vim.

Finally, there are some helpful tips [here](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=15459) (basically, add a macro that does what you want, assign it to a key combination of your choice). This should work no matter the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Personnally I use an intermediate editor window (nedit) that would'nt support formatting. That's far from ideal though.

Answer (score 0):

Select your text with the mouse (highlight it), then middle click where you want to paste

Comment: I just tried that - copied from this question to OpenOffice. It pasted formatted text.

Comment: You're confusing things. Openoffice decides to paste the text formatted. What you highlight gets copied as plain text, always. The question is not about the OS, but about the OpenOffice suite.

Comment: Remember, there is no such thing as plain text. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @Adriano - I AM confused. If the text were copied as plain text into memory, the formatting would have been removed before OpenOffice ever saw it, right?

Comment: @Stefan - specifically, I want the pasted text to share the formatting of the destination text, not the source text.

Comment: In most word processing and office software there is a special paste function that can paste text without any formatting.

Comment: Word, for example, has a "Paste Special..." function right next to Paste in the menu.

Comment: @Stefan - yes, I know there is a special paste function. I listed that in my known workarounds when I asked the question. What I want is to change the default so that I don't have to specify each time that I don't want the formatting. I never want the formatting. It feels like saying "give me a hamburger, and leave out the chocolate sauce." If I wanted chocolate sauce, I would say so. Leaving it out should be the default. Or at least let me SET that as the default. Don't make me say "hold the chocolate sauce" every time I order.

Comment: @Nathan: your analogy is faulty. You don't want formatting, but I'm not sure that most people copying text to a rich text Office program share your view. It's not so much 'hold the chocolate sauce' as 'hold the ketchup on those fries' (I really don't like ketchup)